# Making TinyMCE Only Edit After A Certain Line

Tags: php, tinymce

I'm trying to make a news editor, but the problem I'm having is that I save all the info for the post in a single text file. I'm using TinyMCE for editing of web pages, so ideally I would like to use TinyMCE for this too.

My question is, is there a way to specify something like "only edit after line 2" with TinyMCE? Maybe loading the contents of the file in to a variable (using PHP) and removing the first two lines, and then only overwriting everything past the first two lines?

Thanks!

Comment: sounds like you should be using a db in the first place.

Comment: I'm with Dagon here. Saving posts in text files is highly inefficient. You would be better served using a DB and separating the structure from the content. It would make it much easier to edit content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the content of the first 2 lines into a common ancestor(if not available yet) and give the ancestor the class **mceNonEditable**

**Please Note:** This will only affect the WYSIWYG-mode, the HTML-source will still be editable if the HTML-control is present.

But this I only suggest if you need to have the 2 lines visible inside the editor, otherwise I would prefer to split the parts on server-side.

Comment: Ah this looks promising. I doubt you'll see this comment, but by "common ancestor" do you mean like a `div` or something?